# How can I increase tx queue number under ubuntu wan interface?

Tags: ubuntu, queue

I want to increase the tx queue on ubuntu.

```
pidda@pidda:~$ ls /sys/class/net/wlp1s0/queues/
rx-0 tx-0
pidda@pidda:~$ sudo ip link set wlp1s0 numtxqueues 7
```

```
pidda@pidda:~$ echo $?
0
pidda@pidda:~$ ls /sys/class/net/wlp1s0/queues/
rx-0 tx-0
pidda@pidda:~$
```

Though the command execution is successfully, the tx queue is still one. It would be very helpful to point me to some doc which explains on tx queue.
Is this a hardware limit? or is there any way to increase it?

Comment: the nearest approach could be a hint from [süße distribution](https://www.suse.com/de-de/support/kb/doc/?id=000019932) but why would you want to do it?

Comment: The above link explains on how to increase tx queue length. But I tried similar thing for tx queue number, but did not work. This ask for my research with traffic classification using ubuntu.